# Select box onchange event with only one <option>

Tags: javascript

The onchange event works great and populates my input (textbox) just fine, but when the onchange event is applied to the drop down box with only 1 single option in it, it does not work. How can I get the onchange to fire even if, there is one or multiple items?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(x) {

    var x = document.getElementById(x).options[document.getElementById(x).selectedIndex].text

    document.getElementById('output').value = x

}//end of function
</script>

</head>

<body>
<select id="drop1" onchange="test(this.id)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="drop2" onchange="test(this.id)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select> 
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="output">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just can't figure out, how to change option when only one is available?

Comment: 'drop2' only has one option. If I select it, I would like the value to appear in my textbox.

Comment: How is the `<select>` populated?  On the server, or by JavaScript?

Comment: OK, gilly3 has a good answer for that, in addition to his suggestions, also `onfocus` might be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one item, it never will change.  Try `onblur` instead.  Or maybe `onclick`, depending on what you are *actually* trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You could add an empty option at the top of every select box, or perhaps an option that just says -Select-. Then, if necessary, alter your script to ignore the empty selection.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question in case it can help somebody in 2020. I had the same problem populating data from the database into the form  where there was a single data and I was able to solve this way. In the example am gonna use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) for illustrations.

First you have to empty the select element using [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function.

```
$('#drop2').empty();
```

Secondly add an empty value into the select using [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#drop2').append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
```

After that now you can go ahead to add your data into the select element because they are going to be two options, one empty while the other carries the data.

Finally populate your data from server this way using [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in success function

```
success:function(response){
                        $('#drop2').empty().append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
                        response.forEach((item)=>{
                            $('#drop2').append("<option value='"+item[]+"'>"+item[1]</option>");

                        });
```

I have used the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `.forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

If you've come here in 2022 then this is the answer you are looking for:

The easiest solution is to simply put `hidden` in a 'placeholder' option tag.

```
<select>
  <option hidden value="dontselect">Spinny wheely bois</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

This means that there will always be 2 or more options in the select but the placeholder option does not show in the drop-down list (so won't be able to be selected). The placeholder should be the first option tag inside select just to make your life easier.

But it does mean that when you click the one actual option you'll trigger onChange as internally the select is changing value.